# Coroutine 'nokia.maps.map.render.p2d.Engine#_renderCo' aborted abnormally with exception

Tags: here-api

I've updated HereMaps JavaScript from 2.2.4 to 2.5.3 and the map has stopped working on Chrome (version 31.0.1650.57 m). Firefox and IE work as before.

On the console I see the message many times

Coroutine 'nokia.maps.map.render.p2d.Engine#_renderCo' aborted abnormally with exception base.js:158
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Does anyone have a hint of what might be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some sample code to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to answer your specific problem without seeing your code, but I am able to produce a similar error which may help you track down your issue.

If you are getting **multiple** error messages, then it is likely that the JavaScript library itself is calling something periodically. From the text of the error it likely that the library is running a [Coroutine](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.util.Coroutine.html), which is usually used for threading within the application.

The error I can produce is in a callback - if I add an overlay to the map, and deliberately try to access a non-existent property within my code I can get:

```
Coroutine 'nokia.maps.map.render.p2d.Engine#_renderCo' aborted abnormally with exception base.js:158
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined
```

This was because I added a typo as follows:

I changed the reference from `foo.something.bar` in the callback to  `foo.does_not_exist.bar`. So I guess somewhere in your callbacks you are referencing `foo.something.body` in your callback - it could be in a listener for example.

Another possibility, is that you are switching directly to `Display.SATELLITE` when you are creating the map - this is no longer allowed:

Taken from the News feed on [developer.here.com](http://developer.here.com):

> **Breaking changes with 2.5.3**
>
> The new rendering engine requires the map to be initialized
>   asynchronously. If you want to change the center, zoom level or the
>   base map type the API now requires the application to wait for the
>   `"displayready"` event to be fired. This event is only fired once.
>   Please refer to the developer's guide (section "[Beyond the Basic Map Application](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics/building-on-simplest-scenario.html)
>   ") for details.

Comment: The problem was indeed because of the "breaking changes with 2.5.3". There was a combination of panning and centering that was done before "displayready".

The code didn't contain any reference to Display.SATELLITE or had foo.something.body. Also, there were multiple error messages, as suggested above.

Comment: My solution to the problem was to add a "displayready" listener and do further initialization inside that listener.