# HERE Maps on Android freezes browser, breaking ajax requests on iOS

Tags: android, ios

I am using HERE Maps to show a map letting users choose a location of interest. It works fine on desktop, but on mobile devices I am experiencing some problems.

On Android devices, if I create a map using

```
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById("map"), {
    // Initial center and zoom level of the map
    center: startCoordinate,
    zoomLevel: 5,
    components: [
      new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
      new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(),
      new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar()
    ]
  }
);
```

the browser freezes after a few seconds. You can test this at [karmap.com](http://karmap.com); try to scroll down to the very bottom to find the map. If I remove the code shown above the browser won't freeze anymore (but I won't get the map, of course).

Another problem occurs, when loading the page on iOS devices; in the form at the bottom you can find an input box named "Place of Birth". After typing 3 letters or more I start an ajax request to find suitable city names. This doesn't work if I use the following code (right under the code snippet to create the map):

```
map.removeComponent(map.getComponentById("zoom.MouseWheel"));
map.set("baseMapType", map.SATELLITE); // Activates satellite imagery on the display
```

If I comment that code out, the ajax calls work fine.

For me, that is some strange side effect! Does anyone have a clue what is going on?

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: I'm not sure if this advice will work in your case, but whenever I see the line `map.set("baseMapType", map.SATELLITE);` I think you may be falling foul of the _Breaking Changes for 2.5.3_ try setting the map type within a `displayready` listener as described [here](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics/building-on-simplest-scenario.html). A similar issue was described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094457)

Comment: Thanks for your input! After you mentioned the breaking changes for 2.5.3 I realised I was working with an outdated version of nokia here maps :( After updating, everything is working fine :)